# TeXMaker: Autocompletion of brackets

Tags: texmaker, editors

I have just switched to TeXmaker from TeXstudio since I am working on Mac now.

I am wondering if there is a possibility of setting TeXmaker to autocomplete `()`, `[]`, `{}`, since I extensively use these symbols in math text.

Comment: There is a build of TeXstudio available via Macports, though note that: *'The OS X version is experimental. Since none of the currently active developers is using OS X, we cannot thoroughly test it. We do our best to also support OS X but be prepared that there may be some issues.'* (quote from the TeXstudio webpage)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That's why I switched to texmaker, which is not experimental under mac environment.